# Simple refactoring sql query

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005, refactoring

I have the table with rows:

```
ID          CountryCode Status
----------- ----------- -----------
2           PL          1
3           PL          2
4           EN          1
5           EN          1
```

and by the query

```
SELECT *
  FROM [TestTable]
  WHERE Status = 1 AND CountryCode NOT IN (SELECT CountryCode
  FROM [TestTable]
  WHERE Status != 1)
```

I get all countrycodes which hasn't status value = 2

```
ID          CountryCode Status
----------- ----------- -----------
4           EN          1
5           EN          1
```

I feel that this query could be more simpler and clearer.

How can I change it?

Best regards

**EDIT**

PL can't be in result  because has a record with status 2

**EDIT**

Script to create and fill table:

```
USE [DatabaseName]
GO
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[TestTable](
    [ID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [CountryCode] [nvarchar](2) NOT NULL,
    [Status] [int] NOT NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]

INSERT INTO dbo.TestTable
          ( CountryCode, Status )
  VALUES  ( 'PL', -- CountryCode - nvarchar(2)
            1  -- Status - int
            )

INSERT INTO dbo.TestTable
          ( CountryCode, Status )
  VALUES  ( 'PL', -- CountryCode - nvarchar(2)
            2  -- Status - int
            )

INSERT INTO dbo.TestTable
          ( CountryCode, Status )
  VALUES  ( 'EN', -- CountryCode - nvarchar(2)
            1  -- Status - int
            )
INSERT INTO dbo.TestTable
          ( CountryCode, Status )
  VALUES  ( 'EN', -- CountryCode - nvarchar(2)
            1  -- Status - int
            )
```

Comment: Are 1 & 2 the only statuses... or are there others too where the MIN/MAX application might otherwise fail...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First:  Never use `SELECT *` in often used code.  Especially in production.  Call out your columns.

Soap-Box over.

Note: i haven't tried this, and I don't currently have the management studio installed, so I can't test it.  But I think you want something like this:

```
Select Id, CountryCode, Status
From [TestTable] t
Where Status <> 2
And Not Exists(select status from [TestTable] t2 
                             where t2.Status = 2 
                             and t2.CountryCode = tt.CountryCode)
```

At the least, you've got the right idea: if you only want the CountryCodes which do not (on any record) correspond to Status = 2, you need to get everything with status 1, and then exclude any existing rows with have a matching row with status 2.  I may have the specific syntax for Not Exists incorrect, though.

Answer (score 3):

```
select T1.*
from TestTable as T1
  left outer join
    (
      select distinct CountryCode
      from TestTable as T1
      where Status <> 1  
    ) as T2
    on T1.CountryCode = T2.CountryCode
where
  T1.Status = 1 and
  T2.CountryCode is null
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want all entries where `Status` does not have the value 2, try this:

```
SELECT *
  FROM [TestTable]
 WHERE Status != 2
```

EDIT: To prevent a country code where any distinct entry has an unwanted value, try the `GROUP BY` and `HAVING` clauses:

```
  SELECT CountryCode
    FROM [TestTable]
GROUP BY CountryCode
HAVING MAX(Status) = 1 AND MIN(Status) = 1
```

Comment: I've updated my answer with a query that avoids explicit nested queries and joins

Comment: That will not work, because T-SQL requires group by columns to be used in an aggregate function or listed in the group by clause. Where you thinking of MySQL?

Comment: Yay, teamwork! I don't have an SQL server 2005 I can test this on, but a little collaboration goes a long way :-)

Answer (score 0):

```
 SELECT distinct(country) FROM table WHERE value <> 2
```